# PHP getting data from HTML table to update MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a little problem, what I need is to read data from this HTML table, problem is I do not know how much table rows I'll have because I put data in it from MySQL select, so what I really want is after select, to add some data in the HTML table to be specific:

```
<td><input type="text" size="5px"></td>
```

and on button click to read data from all new table rows inputs.

```
<table style="display:inline">
<tr>
<td></td>
<th>Home team</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<th>Away team</th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$Tim1=mysql_result($result,$i,"HomeTeamID");    
$Tim1Name=mysql_result($result,$i,"HomeTeam");
$Tim2=mysql_result($result,$i,"AwayTeamID");
$Tim2Name=mysql_result($result,$i,"AwayTeam");      
$rez=mysql_result($result,$i,"MatchID");        

?>
<tr>
<td class="ID" id="<?php echo $rez;?>"><input value="<?php echo $rez;?>" 
 name="<?php echo $rez;?>" type="hidden" style="display: none">
</td>
<td><label style="padding-right:10px" ><?php echo($Tim1Name); ?></label></td>

<td><input type="text" size="5px"></td>

<td><label>:</label></td>

<td><input type="text" size="5px"></td>

<td><label style="padding-left:10px"><?php echo($Tim2Name); ?></label></td>
</tr>

        <?php
        $i++;
    }   
    ?>
 <tr align="right" style="padding-top:5px">
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td><input type="submit" value="Insert" name="Insert"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

If you did not understand my question,  ask what ever you want and I'll answer.

Comment: so you want to display data in tabular format, after you get data from database, right?

Comment: I can't understand means you insert first data and then counting it?

Comment: no no , data is displayed as i want that is cool , i just want after i add new data inside this
    <td><input type="text" size="5px"></td>
to read it with php, so i can use that data to update MySQL table

I have form method="post" , so on button click i just want to read all data and use it to update table

Comment: so what you want is an input using an array structure and with a key which is the index of the record ie <input name="data[<?php echo mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");  ?>][HomeTeam]" value="<?php echo $Tim1Name; ?>" />  you can the loop through $_POST['data'] with $key as the id of the record to update and $value['HomeTeam'] as the value to update

Comment: What you mean by new rows? you are inserting rows at runtime in your html table?

Comment: No , i want to read data from HTML table so i can use that data to update MySQL table

Comment: Can you provide table information, ie table names, what fields are indexes, the query you used to get the info. This will allow us to create the update queries

Comment: guys i do not have problem with update queries i know how to deal with it , my main and only problem is to read data from HTML table, specific to get data from 2 text boxes in middle of HTML table and nothing else ... i tried provided answers but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the table using JQuery and extract values. I can't understand what is the purpose of reading the data again from the table.. but try the code below:

suppose you have an id for your table,

```
<table id='teams_table'>
```

Then use this JQuery script to loop through table rows;

```
var cells = 6; //number of collumns
var cell_text = '';

$('tr',$('#teams_table')).each(function(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < cells ; i++){
    cell_text = $(this).find('td').eq(i).text();
    //do what ever you want with cell_text
  }
});
```

If you want more help, please describe your scenario in more detail.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: i have tried this way and i added
alert(cell_text); 
just to check what i get as result ... and it reads everything but a textbox text i enter

Comment: for that, put `if(i == 5) cell_text = $(this).find('input').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Try To use the following

first of all add a jquery library in you head section

and then built a function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.insert').click(function({

$('.testValues').each(function(){
var Values=$(this).attr('title');


$(this).val(Values);
$(this).attr('title','');
});
});
```

});

And Change your HTML to Affect above code as following

```
<table style="display:inline">
<tr>
<td></td>
<th>Home team</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<th>Away team</th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$Tim1=mysql_result($result,$i,"HomeTeamID");    
$Tim1Name=mysql_result($result,$i,"HomeTeam");
$Tim2=mysql_result($result,$i,"AwayTeamID");
$Tim2Name=mysql_result($result,$i,"AwayTeam");      
$rez=mysql_result($result,$i,"MatchID");        

?>
<tr>
<td class="ID" id="<?php echo $rez;?>"><input value="<?php echo $rez;?>" 
 name="<?php echo $rez;?>" type="hidden" style="display: none">
</td>
<td><label style="padding-right:10px" ><?php echo($Tim1Name); ?></label></td>

<td><input type="text" size="5px" class="testvalues" title="<?php echo($Tim1); ?>"></td>

<td><label>:</label></td>

<td><input type="text" size="5px" class="testvalues" title="<?php echo($Tim2); ?>"></td>

<td><label style="padding-left:10px"><?php echo($Tim2Name); ?></label></td>
</tr>

        <?php
        $i++;
    }   
    ?>
 <tr align="right" style="padding-top:5px">
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td><input type="button" value="Insert" name="Insert" class="insert"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Since i did not debug the code so check your error console of putting that code and don't forget to add library of jquery